# python : re how to replace everything beside some pattern

Tags: python, regex

```
re_filter = re.compile(r'(?s)<div style="border.*?</div>')
s = re_filter.sub('', s)
```

this substitutes lines with constructed pattern.
But how can I substitute everything beside the constructed pattern ?

Comment: I want to remove all the texts and leave only the lines that meet the pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = ''.join(re_filter.findall(s))
```